# AngularJS, manage binary data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, escaping, download, binaryfiles

I want to download a file with angularjs (1.0.8) from a service Spring. I use a POST request because I have to pass a piece of HTML as parament, and browsers have limitation with length of query string. Here my code:

```
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/export/pdf',
        data: "html=" + graphHtml.outerHTML,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        transformResponse: function(data, headersGetter){
            return data;
        }
    }).success(function(data) {
        console.log("Type '" + typeof(data) + "'");
        var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
        hiddenElement.href = 'data:application/pdf,' + data;
        hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
        hiddenElement.download = 'myFile.pdf';
        hiddenElement.click();
    });
```

I notice that the "data" received is already in "string" format! I see many (?) question point, and when type

```
    typeof(data)
```

i receive "string". I don't want this interpretation of my raw data. When i try to write data in a file, the size is double respect original file! I know it is for "string interpretation" of binary data that instead wanted read as binary. Has anyone a solution for see "data" in raw format and not as string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set $http responseType in during config. and do something like [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/)

Comment: This answer could be improved by summarizing the information linked, especially in the case that the link goes dead.

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 5):

In a $http configuration object, specify

```
responseType : "blob"
```

to get response data returned in a binary format.

Otherwise, default response format is a String. For other choices for responseType, see AngularJS API reference.

Comment: I added responseType : "blob", but the data reced by servlet is still in UTF-8 format. Here is the code : $http({method: 'PUT', url: "api/clients/" + $routeParams.clientId + scope.resource.path,
                            data: rsc, timeout:300000, responseType: "blob",
                            headers:{'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}})