# Pdf is corrupted when viewing via javascript Blob

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf, encoding, utf-8

I have an endpoint that returns a pdf file:

URL: `https://localhost:44300/common/api/report`

Response headers:

```
access-control-expose-headers: Accept-Ranges
cache-control: no-cache,no-store
content-disposition: inline; filename=ChangeOfOwnershipReport.pdf
content-length: 51720
content-type: application/pdf
date: Wed, 05 Oct 2022 00:19:28 GMT
expect-ct: max-age=31536001,enforce
expires: -1
pragma: no-cache
referrer-policy: strict-origin
server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-robots-tag: noindex, nofollow, noarchive, nosnippet
x-server-time: 2022-10-05T00:19:28.9668294Z
x-sourcefiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcRGV2ZWxvcFxwdHh5elxSb2NrZW5kLkJlZHJvY2suV2ViLkh0bWxcY29tbW9uXGFwaVxyZXBvcnRccmVwb3J0cmVzdWx0?=
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
```

The response's body is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body style='height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; margin:0px; background-color: rgb(82, 86, 89);'>
<embed name='08F500DBA0A34C7A553145482363CF67'
    style='position:absolute; left: 0; top: 0;'
    width='100%'
    height='100%'
    src='about:blank'
    type='application/pdf'
    internalid='08F500DBA0A34C7A553145482363CF67'>
</body>
</html>
```

When manually typing that URL in a browser, the pdf is generated and displays fine.

I'm trying to use angularjs to make the HTTP request, and then open the pdf in a new window:

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://localhost:44300/common/api/report'
}).then(function success(response) {                    
    let utf8Encode = new TextEncoder();
    let byteArray = utf8Encode.encode(response.data);

    var file = new Blob([byteArray], { type: "application/pdf" });
    var fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    
    $window.open(fileUrl, '_blank');
}, function error(response) {
    
});
```

However this results in a blank pdf (but with the correct number of pages).

I put a breakpoint in the angularjs code to see the value of `response`:

[image]

For some reason the preview of `response.data` is different to the actual value (see highlighted section in screenshot above).

Does this have something to do with the pdf being blank?

Here's the actual text from the screenshot:

Preview:

```
%PDF-1.7\r\n4 0 obj\r\n<</Type /Page/Parent 3 0 R/Cont…Ȕ\x00\x00\r\nendstream\r\nendobj\r\nstartxref\r\n51348\r\n%%EOF\r\n
```

Actual value of `response.data`:

```
%PDF-1.7\r\n4 0 obj\r\n<</Type /Page/Parent 3 0 R/Contents 5 0 R/MediaBox [0 0 841.90002441 595.29998779]/Resources<</Font<</FA...
```

Pdfs can be downloaded here:

[Good pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ixylf483aw7582c/ChangeOfOwnershipReport.pdf?dl=0)

[Bad pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/an8t6vjnzu4i1ob/ChangeOfOwnershipReportBroken.pdf?dl=0)

I saved both pdfs and can see the following differences:

Good pdf size = 51720 bytes

Bad pdf size = 91476 bytes

Here are the first 20 rows of 16 bytes from HxD for the good pdf:

```
25 50 44 46 2D 31 2E 37 0D 0A 34 20 30 20 6F 62 6A 0D 0A 3C 3C 2F 54 79 70 65 20 2F 50 61 67 65 2F 50 61 72 65 6E 74 20 33 20 30 20 52 2F 43 6F 6E 74 65 6E 74 73 20 35 20 30 20 52 2F 4D 65 64 69 61 42 6F 78 20 5B 30 20 30 20 38 34 31 2E 39 30 30 30 32 34 34 31 20 35 39 35 2E 32 39 39 39 38 37 37 39 5D 2F 52 65 73 6F 75 72 63 65 73 3C 3C 2F 46 6F 6E 74 3C 3C 2F 46 41 41 41 41 48 20 37 20 30 20 52 2F 46 41 41 41 42 41 20 31 30 20 30 20 52 3E 3E 3E 3E 2F 47 72 6F 75 70 20 3C 3C 2F 54 79 70 65 2F 47 72 6F 75 70 2F 53 2F 54 72 61 6E 73 70 61 72 65 6E 63 79 2F 43 53 2F 44 65 76 69 63 65 52 47 42 3E 3E 3E 3E 0D 0A 65 6E 64 6F 62 6A 0D 0A 35 20 30 20 6F 62 6A 0D 0A 3C 3C 2F 4C 65 6E 67 74 68 20 31 32 20 30 20 52 2F 46 69 6C 74 65 72 20 2F 46 6C 61 74 65 44 65 63 6F 64 65 3E 3E 73 74 72 65 61 6D 0D 0A 78 9C CD 5C DB 8E 1E C7 71 7E 95 B9 0A C4 00 9C F4 F9 A0 3B 2A 8A 65 07 82 22 DB 04 72 61 E4 82 FE F9 4B 22 B0 BB 94 C5 55 02 3F 13 1F C1 2F 97 AA AE AA EE
```

Here are the first 20 rows of 16 bytes from HxD for the bad pdf:

```
25 50 44 46 2D 31 2E 37 0D 0A 34 20 30 20 6F 62 6A 0D 0A 3C 3C 2F 54 79 70 65 20 2F 50 61 67 65 2F 50 61 72 65 6E 74 20 33 20 30 20 52 2F 43 6F 6E 74 65 6E 74 73 20 35 20 30 20 52 2F 4D 65 64 69 61 42 6F 78 20 5B 30 20 30 20 38 34 31 2E 39 30 30 30 32 34 34 31 20 35 39 35 2E 32 39 39 39 38 37 37 39 5D 2F 52 65 73 6F 75 72 63 65 73 3C 3C 2F 46 6F 6E 74 3C 3C 2F 46 41 41 41 41 48 20 37 20 30 20 52 2F 46 41 41 41 42 41 20 31 30 20 30 20 52 3E 3E 3E 3E 2F 47 72 6F 75 70 20 3C 3C 2F 54 79 70 65 2F 47 72 6F 75 70 2F 53 2F 54 72 61 6E 73 70 61 72 65 6E 63 79 2F 43 53 2F 44 65 76 69 63 65 52 47 42 3E 3E 3E 3E 0D 0A 65 6E 64 6F 62 6A 0D 0A 35 20 30 20 6F 62 6A 0D 0A 3C 3C 2F 4C 65 6E 67 74 68 20 31 32 20 30 20 52 2F 46 69 6C 74 65 72 20 2F 46 6C 61 74 65 44 65 63 6F 64 65 3E 3E 73 74 72 65 61 6D 0D 0A 78 EF BF BD EF BF BD 5C DB 8E 1E EF BF BD 71 7E EF BF BD EF BF BD 0A EF BF BD 00 EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 3B 2A EF BF BD 65 07 EF BF BD 22 EF BF
```

Here's a screenshot showing the difference (good on the left, bad on the right).

They are identical up until offset 10D:

[image]

How can I get the correct bytes from the response in the javascript so the pdf is not corrupted?

I'm using Google Chrome 105.0.5195.102 (Official Build) (64-bit) and Windows 10.

Comment: *"For some reason the preview of response.data is different to the actual value"* - the **preview** is shortened as is indicated by use of the ellipse "...".

Comment: @mkl good point! Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: The pdf is damaged by the conversions of the binary data to text and back to bytes. You need to use the binary response data directly.

Comment: @mkl how can I access the binary response data in angularjs? Unfortunately the `response.data` is a string.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know angularjs details and can only state the cause of the damage.

Comment: @mkl I was able to access the binary data using `responseType : "blob"` in the `$http` config (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24949374/2063755). Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.